# Unable to get a saved data in adobe air ELS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, adobe

I am trying to save and get data from an adobe air application with the following code. buts its just keep alerting only undefined. Can someone find the error?

```
            function saveData(n, v){
                var bytes = new air.ByteArray(); 
                bytes.writeUTFBytes(v); 
                return air.EncryptedLocalStore.setItem(n, bytes);   
            }

            function getData(n){
                var storedValue = air.EncryptedLocalStore.getItem(n); 
                return air.trace(storedValue.readUTFBytes(storedValue.length));
            }

            saveData('item1', 'value1');
            alert(getData('item1'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try removing the `air.trace` function

```
function saveData(n:String, v:String):void
{
    var bytes = new air.ByteArray(); 
    bytes.writeUTFBytes(v);

    air.EncryptedLocalStore.setItem(n, bytes);   
}

function getData(n):String
{
    var storedValue = air.EncryptedLocalStore.getItem(n); 

    return storedValue.readUTFBytes(storedValue.length);
}

saveData("item1", "value1");
alert(getData("item1"));
```

Comment: that worked. thanks ;) why its not working in this way? Its the code given in adobe tuts

Comment: well, in your code you are returning a tracing function, which works fine since there is no return type for the getData() function so anything can be returned, but a string is what is returned from ByteArray.readUTFBytes() and a function isn't a string.  personally, i don't program AS3 with AIR in this way (is it web programming?) so i'm a bit unfamiliar with it.  perhaps it's not suppose to be strictly typed?  can you shrare the link of the tutorial?

Comment: Sure, here is the link http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WSd10e5fbe156f4b9b219e2108120012b9a34-7fff.html

Comment: ah, yes.  the tutorial example isn't returning a value by calling a function.  it's simply tracing the result.  :)

Comment: can you help me with this too?

http://pastebin.com/igySDr1M


its not alerting the "no" value after trying the above code.  any Idea?

Comment: please post it as a new question.

Comment: Sure, here is the question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13221399/unable-to-find-whats-wrong-with-this-code-for-adobe-air

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19048/discussion-between-user632347-and-thedarkin1978)